# Powershell script runs at logon-GPO; It runs fine if the user is domain admin, but does not run for domain/authenticated users

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have a Powershell script  runs as users login. I have tested ,  It runs fine if the user is domain admin, but does not run for domain users.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$username=$env:username
$date=Get-Date -format M-d-yy-HHmm
$Source= "\\FServer\Sharefolder\$username"
$Destination="\\Fserver2\Sharefolder2\$username"
$Log=\\Fileserver2\Sharefolder3\Temp\Log-$username-$date.txt"
If ($Source-and $Destination) {
  ROBOCOPY $Source $Destination "/E" "/S" "/SEC" "/XD" "AppData" /LOG+:log
}
```

In the GPO I have allowed the Authenticated users as well as Domain users.( Security filtering).
It works for Domain admin accounts, but does not RUN for domain users.
Is there a way to invoke/ run script for non-admin users ?
also I have set / checked the permissions for source Destinations folders.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [1] setting the execution policy IN a file ... only changes the current environment. that does not change things when starting the file - so you may be seeing an execution policy glitch between starting the PoSh environemnt and running the file. ///// [2] you have several UNC style paths ... but start them with only ONE `\`. that should be TWO of them.

Comment: Domain user accounts have access to both the source and destination  the script runs fine for admin accounts.

I have created a a test account that is part of domain users , script does not run at all.

As you can see the log file is created if the there is copy from source to destination is completed or not.

I have also tried to change Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass. this did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [1] you still show the UNC paths with only ONE starting \. please fix that. ///// [2] your robocopy call shows /LOG+:log` ... shouldn't that be /LOG+:$log? ///// [3] if those are just typing errors, then you seem to have a permission problem. that an admin account works and normal accounts do NOT work, seems to indicate the the problem is permissions related.

Comment: when you say permission related do you mean , users don't have the permission to copy folders from source or destination ?

Comment: I have looked at the permissions for both folders and added domain users(source & destination).

Comment: i would add LOTS of diagnostic logging to your script to see what is happening. start with the basic `Start-Transcript` and then add logging in ever increasing detail. there are quite a few well written logging scripts on the PSGallery site.